# Geometry Node : Grid rolling transition

Tags: geometry-nodes

I Want to achieve a geometry node setup where my grid can be rolled and transitioned to a planer shape.

Kind of like this picture.[image]

Comment: and what did you try so far? any node tree?

Comment: Honestly I am not able to wrap my head around the rolling part. Transition should be easy with spline parameter. Can not find any tutorial where the plane is bent like this.

Answer (score 3):

you can start with this node setup - it is just a beginning, but i think you can start with it and finetune this to your needs.

[image]

[image]

The "tricky" part is here, that you can change the circle/plane shape change by the y value. Of course you can finetune that with a float curve node or something else.